# How to open all window in one monitor for dual monitor system

Tags: windows-8.1, multiple-monitors

Recently I bought a monitor and did set up with my laptop as dual monitor. Now whenever I open a new window, file or software it always open in the laptop first and then I have to move it to the extended big monitor. But I want to know is there any way to set up so that whenever I open a file, window or software it will automatically open in the external window? Also I can see my desktop only in the laptop. Is there any way to change the desktop to show in the extended window rather than showing in laptop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click anywhere on your desktop and select "Screen Resolution". You will see the two monitors in that configuration window. Select the bigger one you have and tick the "Make this my main display".

If you also want to disable your laptop's display, then press "Windows+P" and select "Only external display" (or something along those lines).